# MySQL database with list of URLs - how to check for broken links?

Tags: mysql, uri

I have a MySQL database with a list of URLs that I want to check from time to time for broken links.

```
www.url1.com/product1/site.html
www.url2.com/product2/site.html
www.url3.com/product3/site.html
```

There seems to be no MySQL command like get_content etc.

What I want is a list of all broken links (e.g. returns 404/503) to delete them from the DB. Is there any way to do that at all from the DB directly?

Comment: A database management system like MySQL deals with data, storage and retrieval. It does not know what a `URL` is and what it is for. Not more, not less. You will need to use some additional component. Easiest would be to implement a simple script that periodically checks the URL and can remove any URL it receives an error code upon.

Comment: You need to use some programming language like PHP, connect to database, fetch URLs and checked them - for ex. like here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770903/check-if-links-are-broken-in-php

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if possible at all. This answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments answered it, checking URL links needs to be a separate operation e.g in PHP and cannot be done in the database. Thanks