# load OTHER LINK if not available

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
$mp3Linkger = wp_get_attachment_url($mp3_file_id);

$mp3Link = wp_get_attachment_url($mp3_file_id);
$mp3Link = str_replace( 'example.COM', 'static.example.COM', $mp3Link );

    $playerTag = '[audio mp3="'.$mp3Linkger.'"][/audio]';
```

In the above code

- `$playerTag` loads the link
- `$mp3Linkger` Is broadcast

I want to load `$mp3Link` if `$mp3Linkger` was not available

Not available like Down Server or 404 error and ...

**Update :**

Ways that friends tell / Site loading speed slows down :

```
        function check_url($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mp3Linkger);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $headers['http_code'];
}

        $check_url_status = check_url($mp3Linkger);
if ($check_url_status == '200') {
   $playerTag = '[audio mp3="'.$mp3Linkger.'"][/audio]';
} else {
   $playerTag = '[audio mp3="'.$mp3Link.'"][/audio]'; }
```

I want this process to happen when the user clicks on the link ($playerTag)

That is, if link a is not available, link b will be loaded

.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770903/check-if-links-are-broken-in-php

Comment: This method slows down the site
I'm looking for a way to click

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `@fopen();`.

> fopen — Opens file or URL

| Mode | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 'r' | Open for reading only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file. |

*Source @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php*

```
<?php
/**
* Check if CDN's url is valid, if not return fallback
*/
$test = @fopen( '_Your_CDN_URL_goes_here_', 'r' );
if ( $test !== false ) {
  // CDN's url is valid
  $url = _Your_CDN_URL_goes_here_;
} else {
  // CDN's url isn't valid
  $fallback = _Your_fallback_URL_goes_here_;
}; ?>
```

Comment: Does this process start when the link (Your_CDN_URL_goes_here)  is clicked? Or by loading the site page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770903/check-if-links-are-broken-in-php      Isn't this the first answer and example better? OR
Which speed is better, which one is slow or does it not matter?   I do not want the site loading speed to be slow

Comment: With the first one you're required to use `Curl`, which isn't present by default. `You need to have CURL installed for this to work.` With `@fopen();` you have nothing more to install. `Curl` uses external library and it has a lot more power to customizing the request. `@fopen();` is limited to only just make a GET request of the url without any further customization. Both `@fopen();` and `Curl` support SSL.

Comment: Speed is not different? Site page speed

Comment: a GET request is what is used most of the time to load the differents part of your website. The impact is really low. Both are similar speed wised.

Comment: Did I managed to solve your problem? Don't forget to **`vote up`** and **`accept the answer`**.

Comment: Thank you for sure. Please embed the codes. I do not know your code